# Dashboard Create Gallery missing

Tags: images

I created my own theme from scratch a couple of months ago and all seemed well.  I have debugging turned on and there are no errors.  I am ready to start setting up my portfolio gallery, but I just noticed that I do not have the "create gallery" option available from any area in the media gallery or from the post or page add media setup.  The codex says that this is set up by default, but I have never seen it as an option.  I am running version 5.2.2.  I am not running any plugins other than "Show Current Template".

My question is: 
Is there something I could have put into my functions.php to turn it off?
Is there something I need to do to enable it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you,
Mike Ginter

Answer (score 0):

Now I know why no one was answering.

It looks like I have been a dufus and completely missed that the fine folks at WP moved the "Create Gallery" option from where I was used to having it located after upgrading to the Gutenberg editor.  Oh, well!  I'm surprised where they put it, and that I so easily missed it.  Par for the course.